# Why must a callback to a method in an Android activity be static?

Tags: java, android, static, callback, instance

In a barebones Android application, I want to call a method in the MainActivity instance, from an asynchronous callback in the instance of another class. Why does Java force me to call a static method in the class, rather than a non-static method in the instance itself?

My app has a MainActivity class and a TextToSpeech (TTS) class. From the main activity, I instantiate the class, passing a pointer to the MainActivity instance. Instantiation of the TTS engine is an asynchronous operation. I cannot interact with the TTS instance until it has triggered an onInit() method.

Below is code that works. However, I had imagined that I would be able to call a non-static method in the MainActivity instance, and this appears not to be possible. The code below uses a static call to the MainActivity class itself, so no instance variables are available.

Here are the changes I made to a basic Hello World application in Android Studio.

```
//MainActivity.java
package com.example.callback;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  private static TTS tts; // apparently this has to be static

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    tts = new TTS();
    Log.d("onResume", this.toString());
    // D/Main﹕ com.example.callback.MainActivity@4a014e50

    tts.init(this);
  }

  // Apparently this method has to be static
  public static void ttsReady() {
    tts.speakText("Hello world");
  }
}
```

Custom class.

```
// TTS.java
package com.example.callback;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TTS implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

  private TextToSpeech tts;
  private Activity activity;

  public void init(Activity currentActivity) {
    activity = currentActivity;
    Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    tts = new android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech(context, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
      tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
      Log.d("onInit", activity.toString());
      // D/onInit﹕ com.example.callback.MainActivity@4a014e50

      // activity.ttsReady();
      // The line above does not compile. ttsReady() is not recognized as a
      // method of activity, regardless of whether the tts variable and the
      // ttsReady() method in the MainActivity class are made static or not,
      // Making the activity variable static here has no effect either.

      // The commented line below throws Error:(31, 35)
      // error: non-static method toString() cannot be referenced from a static context
      // So presumably MainActivity is a static variable.
      // Log.d("onInit", MainActivity.toString())

      // This works, if the tts variable and the ttsReady() method in the
      // MainActivity class are made static. Is there a non-static alternative?
      MainActivity.ttsReady();
    }
  }

  // Deprecated signature for speak() used for compatibility with API 20
  // and earlier
  public void speakText(String toSpeak) {
    int mode = android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH;
    // Object hashMap = null; // Causes a "no suitable method error".
    // How is HashMap null not the same as Object null? Using just plain null
    // instead of hashMap also works with no problems.
    HashMap hashMap = null;
    tts.speak(toSpeak, mode, hashMap);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
  if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
    Log.d("onInit", activity.toString());

    ((MainActivity)activity).ttsReady();
  }
}
```

You are not referring to the *instance* of `MainActivity` when you say `MainActivity.ttsReady()`. That is why you can only access static methods. You need to make a call to the instance itself which you have stored in the `activity` variable.

**Edit:**
For a complete solution based on what you're trying to accomplish, I would probably set it up this way:

```
// TTSActivity.java
public abstract class TTSActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

            ttsReady();
        }

    }

    public void speakText(String toSpeak) {
        int mode = android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH;
        tts.speak(toSpeak, mode, null);
    }

    protected TextToSpeech getTts() {
        return tts;
    }

    protected abstract void ttsReady();
}
```

then `MainActivity` becomes:

```
// MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends TTSActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void ttsReady() {
        speakText("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Any `Activity` you want to use TTS in, all  you have to do is extend `TTSActivity` and implements `ttsReady()`.

As you can see, this is much more concise and easier to understand. However, your exact implementation will of course be dependent upon all the requirements you have in your particular application.

Comment: With a declaration like `private MainActivity activity;` and a signature for init like `public void init(MainActivity currentActivity)`, the line `activity.ttsReady();` compiles fine. But hard-coding for `MainActivity` is not feasible. In my full application, I want to create callbacks from the TTS instance to a number of different activities. A quick test shows that the solution is to use a `TTSUser` interface for each activity that requires a callback for ttsReady(). I then use TTSUser in the signature for the init method and cast back to `(Activity)` before calling `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: That's right. Your original question was simply how to access the method in a non-static manner. Designing it well is more involved, but your proposed solution sounds correct. You can also make your interface extend `Activity`, thus eliminating the need to cast it back to call `getApplicationContext()`, assuming you will only be using it from an `Activity` of course and never anything else such as a `Fragment`.

Comment: I've posted an implementation of my proposed solution as an answer for this question. Following your suggestion, I have tried using `interface TTSUser extends Activity`, but that leads to a compile error: `Error:(5, 27) error: interface expected here`. Have I misunderstood? The answer number 3 that I see [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2080730) indicates a technique that does not seem usable in this case. I would be interested to see how to implement your suggestion so that I can call `getApplicationContext()` without casting back to `Activity`.

Comment: Nevermind, I was mixing up my languages for a second ;) I updated my answer with a complete working example for you.

Comment: edited to setup the `TextToSpeech` object in `onCreate()` which is probably the more proper place to do that kind of work.

Comment: Great! Your edit and my understanding of what needed to be edited happened at almost exactly the same time! Thanks for helping me to find an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

@zaventh's answer helped me to realize that a Java instance needs to be cast to the right class or interface for its methods to be found in the inheritance hierarchy. I have now rewritten my barebones project to include an interface that declares the ttsReady() method.

Here is the solution that allows me to access the methods of the MainActivity instance in a generic way.

TTSUser Interface

```
package com.example.callback;

interface TTSUser {
  void ttsReady();
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.callback;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

// TTUser Interface ensures the existence of the ttsReady() method in every instance
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TTSUser {

  private TTS tts; // non-static

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    tts = new TTS();
    tts.init(this);
  }

  public void ttsReady() { // non-static
    tts.speakText("Hello world");
  }
}
```

TTS Class

```
package com.example.callback;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TTS implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

  private TextToSpeech tts;
  private TTSUser activity;

  // Use the TTSUser interface in the signature
  public void init(TTSUser activity) {
    this.activity = activity;

    // Cast to generic Activity, to access .getApplicationContext()
    Context context = ((Activity) activity).getApplicationContext();
    tts = new android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech(context, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
      tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
      activity.ttsReady(); // accessible through the TTSUser interfaceg
    }
  }

  // Deprecated signature for speak() used for compatibility with API 20
  // and earlier
  public void speakText(String toSpeak) {
    int mode = android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH;
    tts.speak(toSpeak, mode, null);
  }
}
```